# Calculate timediff by skipping certain hours

Tags: mysql, date

complaint creation date:`2014-09-16T18:41:42.000Z`

Complaint closed date:`2014-09-17T10:41:42.000Z`

If complaint closed next day after creation date it will skip `(7Pm to 10 Am time)`

Time for closure:1 hour `(Skip Time 7PM to 10 AM)`

Comment: Current difference is 16 hours & you want to remove 15 hours from that, means you want 1 hour as answer. Correct?

Comment: And What if Creation date & Closed date have difference of more than 1 day? Suppose they have difference of 2 days then?

Comment: What about using TIMESTAMPDIFF? you can use timestamdiff ??

Comment: 1 day is correct...does not matter,looking for 1 day only....

Answer (score 0):

This select query is written in SQL Server. I don't know MySql syntax. You can get LOGIC from this query. Try this,

```
select * 
    ,Datediff(dd,CreatedDate,ClosedDate) as D
    ,Datediff(hh,CreatedDate,ClosedDate) as H
    ,Case When Datediff(dd,CreatedDate,ClosedDate) > 0
            Then Datediff(hh,CreatedDate,ClosedDate) - (15 * Datediff(dd,CreatedDate,ClosedDate))
            else Datediff(hh,CreatedDate,ClosedDate)
    End [Time for closure]
from Request
```